# Remove Square Bracket and Breakdown List elements

Tags: python, list

Here is my list.

```
[['john'],
 ['tom','peter'],
 ['sam'],
 ['mary','susan','dan'],
   :
 ['tony']]
```

I would like to remove all the square brackets and break down the list that looks like below.

```
['john',
 'tom',
 'peter',
 'sam',
 'mary',
 'susan',
 'dan',
   :
 'tony']
```

I tried to use `new_lst = ','.join(str(v) for v in lst)` and `(','.join(lst))` but they don't work. And I couldn't think of a way to break down those list elements as well. That will be great if you all have some ideas and approaches on how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: What's that colon there exactly? This is not valid Python syntax. Is this code, or a text file with that content? Or are you just using : to mark elision?

Comment: The short way is `out = list(x for y in lst for x in y)`.  The tricky way is `out = sum(lst,[])`.

Comment: @joanis fixed it up, I was assuming it was a typo also

Comment: It wasn't literally a typo; he was trying to express a vertical ellipsis.

Comment: @joanis, the colon means there are more elements in the list but I just use colon to represent. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. In retrospect, I should have guessed. :)

Comment: okie, rolled back the changes

Comment: @joanis No problem at all. I should have been more clear up front! ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two good ways:

```
out = list(x for y in lst for x in y)
...or...
out = sum(lst,[])
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way:

```py
my_list = [['john'],
 ['tom','peter'],
 ['sam'],
 ['mary','susan','dan'],
 ['tony']]

# flatten the list
my_list = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
print(my_list)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!